# Search folder for filename and copy item to another location

Tags: powershell

Hello in our environment we have the following structure:

```
\\server\share1\Subfolder1\Subfolder3\123456.jpg
\\server\share1\Subfolder2\Subfolder4\456789.jpg
\\server\share2\123456.tif
\\server\share2\456789.tif
```

What I want to do is the following: Check if the item exists in share2 as tif. If so then I want to copy the tif file to the same location as the jpg (share1).

Via `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File` I can get all the files, but I don't know how to compare the filename to share2 and copy the tif file to the same location as the jpg.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
$JpgFiles = Get-ChildItem .\Share1 -Recurse -File -Filter *.jpg

ForEach ($File in $JpgFiles) {
    $TifFile = Get-ChildItem .\Share2 -Recurse -File -Filter *.tif | Where { $_.BaseName -eq $File.BaseName }

    If ($TifFile) { Copy-Item -Path $TifFile.FullName -Destination $File.DirectoryName }
}
```

- Gets all the .jpg files in Share1
- Iterates through each file and compares the `.basename` property to the files in Share2 (basename is the file name without the extension).
- If it returns a file, copies that file to share1

Comment: Move-Item should be Copy-Item to meet OP requirements :)

Comment: But Share1 contains subfolders. So I can add the option "-Recurse" to include the subfolders - that works. But it doesn't copy the tif files from share2 to the same location as the jpg in share1.

Comment: The modification above will put the .tif file in whatever subfolder the jpg file is in now.